# Why exactly does the time-reversal operator need to be anti-linear?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, complex-numbers, time-reversal-symmetry

I checked many books and they all state that [time-reversal operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry) is [anti-linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilinear_map). But why do we need it to be anti-linear? Please explain where this need actually arises.

Answer (score 10):

The Poincare algebra implies
$$
T ( i H ) T^{-1} = - i H 
$$
where $T$ is the time-reversal operator. **(Can you prove this?)**

Now, suppose $T$ is a linear operator, then $T H T^{-1} = - H$. This implies that if $|\Psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian with energy $E$, then $T^{-1} | \Psi \rangle$ has energy $-E$. This implies that the Hamiltonian is not bounded from below, which is not desirable for a unitary theory. Thus, $T$ must be anti-linear.

Answer (score 9):

One argument is based on the preservation of the [CCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation)

$$\tag{1} [x,p]~=~i\hbar~{\bf 1}.$$

Let $T$ be an invertible $\mathbb{R}$-linear operator with the usual [time-reversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry#Anti-unitary_representation_of_time_reversal) properties:

$$\tag{2} TxT^{-1}~=~x\quad\text{and}\quad TpT^{-1}~=~-p.$$

Then

$$\tag{3} Ti\hbar T^{-1}~=~  T[x,p]T^{-1}~=~[TxT^{-1},TpT^{-1}]~=~-[x,p]~=~-i\hbar~{\bf 1},$$

i.e. $T$ is [antilinear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilinear_map)

$$\tag{4} Ti~=~-iT. $$